# Failed to locate jar file for EDI Mapping Model URN 'org.milyn.edi.unedifact:d03b-mapping:1.7.1.0'. Jar must be available on classpath

Tags: java, edi

I am trying to following this tutorial https://sites.google.com/site/smooksorg/documentation/documentation-smooks-1-1-x/examples/example---edi-to-xml but I am getting in the following error:

```
Failed to locate jar file for EDI Mapping Model URN 'org.milyn.edi.unedifact:d03b-mapping:1.7.1.0'.  Jar must be available on classpath.
```

This is my code snippet:

```
public class Main {

    protected static String runSmooksTransform() throws IOException, SAXException, SmooksException {

        // Configure Smooks using a Smooks config...
        //Smooks smooks = new Smooks("smooks-config.xml");

        // Or, configure Smooks programmatically...
        Smooks smooks = new Smooks();
        smooks.setReaderConfig(new UNEdifactReaderConfigurator("urn:org.milyn.edi.unedifact:d03b-mapping:1.7.1.0"));

        try {
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
//I AM GETTING ERROR THIS LINE
            smooks.filterSource(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream("to-xml/apis.txt")), new StreamResult(writer));

            return writer.toString();
        } finally {
            smooks.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, SmooksException {
        System.out.println("\n\n==============Message In==============");
        System.out.println(readInputMessage());
        System.out.println("======================================\n");

        String messageOut = Main.runSmooksTransform();

        System.out.println("==============Message Out=============");
        System.out.println(messageOut);
        System.out.println("======================================\n\n");
    }

    private static String readInputMessage() throws IOException {
        return StreamUtils.readStreamAsString(new FileInputStream("to-xml/apis.txt"));
    }
}
```

and this is my pom xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.milyn</groupId>
        <artifactId>unedifact-examples</artifactId>
        <version>1.5-SNAPSHOT</version> <!-- base pom version - do not remove this comment -->
    </parent>
    <name>Milyn Smooks Example - UN/EDIFACT - To XML</name>
    <artifactId>milyn-smooks-example-unedifact-to-xml</artifactId>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Smooks -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.milyn</groupId>
            <artifactId>milyn-smooks-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.milyn</groupId>
            <artifactId>testres</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.milyn</groupId>
            <artifactId>milyn-edisax-parser</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Smooks EDI Cartridge -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.milyn</groupId>
            <artifactId>milyn-smooks-edi</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.milyn</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>milyn-smooks-edi</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.7.1</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.milyn.edi.unedifact</groupId>
            <artifactId>d99b-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.milyn.edi.unedifact</groupId>
            <artifactId>d95a-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.milyn.edi.unedifact</groupId>
            <artifactId>d95b-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    

</project>
```

What exactly do am I? I don't know where I went wrong? I would be glad if you help.

Comment: I think you should try using newer versions of these dependencies. Looks like for most of them newer version `1.7.1.0` is available. Use this https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=org.milyn.edi.unedifact page to find newest versions of your dependencies.

Comment: I tried but still doesn't work

Comment: Then maybe you are missing https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.milyn.edi.unedifact/d03b-mapping this dependecy?

Comment: @EimantasG still doesn't work.